# Different permissions for different tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I have the following tables in my database

**users**

**comments**

**other_tables**

I want to give read-write permission to **comments** and **users** tables but read-only permission to **other_tables** .How can I do that?

(I searched it on google but didn't find any way)

Comment: `GRANT ALL ON comments TO username@'localhost'` and `GRANT SELECT ON other_tables TO username@'localhost'`

Answer (score 0):

As documented under [`GRANT` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/grant.html#grant-table-privileges):

```
GRANT SELECT                 ON mydb.*        TO user_specification;
GRANT INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON mydb.users    TO user_specification;
GRANT INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON mydb.comments TO user_specification;
```